# Apache fop generated PDF renders hyperlinks by replacing accented characters with '?'

Tags: apache, pdf, character-encoding, apache-fop

I have used Apache FOP 1.1 to programmatically generate PDF. The PDF is supposed to contain name of a document as hyperlink. When I click on the name, it should open the corresponding file. Here is the code:

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:basic-link color="blue" show-destination="new">
        <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@parentFolderPath">
                   <xsl:value-of select="@parentFolderPath" />/<xsl:value-of select="@FileName" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:value-of select="@FileName" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute><xsl:call-template name="writeWithoutOverlap"><xsl:with-param name="data" select="@FileName"/></xsl:call-template>                   
    </fo:basic-link>
</fo:block>
```

This works perfectly fine when I have a file having English characters in the name. However, when I have a file name like this: "étudiant où forêt naïve garçon.docx"  the hyperlink formed in the PDF replaces the accented characters with '?'.

This is a screen shot of the PDF where you can see the malformed hyperlink:
[image: screenshot]

I am using "Arial" font and encoding="UTF-8".

When the name of the file is getting printed correctly, why is the hyperlink giving a problem?

Comment: Does the hyperlink work or doesn't it?

Comment: Ok, then it definitively is not a matter of the font, but of the data that you place in the destination `@FileName`. For debugging I would put a `<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="@FileName"/></xsl:message>` somewhere around your code - could it be that the data is fixed for displaying in your template named `writeWithoutOverlap`? What is the source of the `@FileName`?

Comment: 1. writeWithoutOverlap is a method for continuity. When the string is long, this method makes sure it is wrapped to the next line.
2. @FileName is coming from JSON which is converted to XML. 
In JSON: "FileName":"\u00e9tudiant o\u00f9 for\u00eat na\u00efve gar\u00e7on.docx"
In XML: <jsonObject FileName="étudiant où forêt naïve garçon.docx" mimeType="text/plain"  ... >

Comment: What makes me wonder is the display in the popup, that looks like it uses some accentuation in addition to the base character to which the accent is applied, but then it seems not to find the accent itself. In the text display, the accents are also shifted right as if it would not use proper accented characters from the font...maybe check the font config for the pdf and your available fonts.